# Creating a zip with the library "zip.js" works but throws a type error in the console in Mozilla Firefox 110.0.1

Tags: javascript, zip.js

I use the following source code to create a ZIP archive from several non-empty files:

```
const zipWriter = new zip.ZipWriter(new zip.BlobWriter("application/zip"), { bufferedWrite: true });
const filePromises = values.map(file => zipWriter.add(file.name, new zip.BlobReader(file), {}));
return Promise.all(filePromises)
              .then(() => zipWriter.close())
              .then(zipBlob => {
                  const archiveDocumentFileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(zipBlob);
                  const anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
                  anchorElement.href = archiveDocumentFileUrl;
                  anchorElement.download = "archive.zip";
                  anchorElement.click();
                  URL.revokeObjectURL(archiveDocumentFileUrl);
                  return Promise.resolve(anchorElement.download);
              })
              .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I use the library "[zip.js](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js)". I cannot use async and await because NetBeans 17 doesn't handle those keywords correctly. I have the following error in Mozilla Firefox 110:

> TypeError: Can not close stream after closing or error

It happens in this part of zip.js source code, even in the full (without minification) version:
`await o.pipeThrough(f).pipeTo(c,{preventAbort:!0});try{await c.close()}catch(e){}`

C is a WritableStream. Is it an expected error? How can I get rid of it? By the way, it doesn't prevent the library from working but maybe there's something really wrong in my source code above.

Comment: I just published the version `2.6.82` of zip.js which might fix this issue. Please let me know if this version works better.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try as soon as possible, probably this week. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @check_ca It doesn't fix the issue :s

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It looks like I did not fix the issue properly in the built files (i.e. from the `/dist` folder). That might explain why you're still seeing the error. I've just published the version `2.6.83` which hopefully should fix it.

Comment: I'm going to give it a try today or Friday in the worst case. Actually, it's my role to thank you, I would have to write a similar library (in worse) if yours didn't exist. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @check_ca It works like a charm, thank you so much. The bug was always reproducible in my case, the bug fix does the right job :)

Comment: Great! Thank you for the feedback, I'm really glad to hear this bug is fixed and that zip.js fulfills  your needs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in lib.js 2.6.83.